# Centering the links in a horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigation

First time messing around with a grid layout. Here is what I have so far:

http://fordsseafoodrockhall.com/marina/index.html#

My question is, how to I center the links in my Horizontal nav bar? As can be seen Im left with a little extra space on the right side then I am on the left.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <ul class="nav-bar">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marina</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Amenities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yacht Club</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar {
height: 40px;
background: #435d78;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 0;
color: #fff;
text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your existing code:

```
.nav-bar {
    display: flex;
}

.nav-bar > li.active {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property distributes free space among sibling elements with the property applied.

Set `display: flex` on the parent in order to enable the use of flex properties.